# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined when making AirTable API call with NextJS 13.4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, airtable

I'm learning the new App router using NextJS 13.4 and have come across an error when attempting to make an external api call.

I actually receive all of the data properly from Airtable but because Next throws this error it causes my try catch to break. I cannot for the life of me figure out what is throwing this error and how to fix it.

Here is the error it is throwing:

```
- error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:254:61)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I am making the initial call from a client component located at `/app/dashboard/page.js`.

page.js looks something like this:

```
'use client'

import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Dashboard = () => {

  useEffect(() => {

    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const res = await fetch('/api/jobs', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'id': '123'
          }
        });

        const data = await res.json();
        console.log("hello", data); // I never hit this console log because the catch below catches the error

      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      Hello World
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Then I have my handler located at `/app/api/jobs/route.js`

route.js looks something like this:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { jobs } from "../../../utils/Airtable";
 
export async function GET(req) {

  let headers = await req.headers.get('id'); // this logs out the headers just fine

  let recordsArr = [];

  try {
        jobs.select({
            view: 'Grid view',
            fields: ['Project Lead'],
            filterByFormula: `AND({Project Lead} = 'Jane Doe', AND({Created Day}, '6/1/23'))`
        }).eachPage(function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
                recordsArr.push(...records);
                
                try {
                    fetchNextPage();
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    return;
                };
            }, function done(err) { 

                if (err) {
                    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({message: 'Error'})) 
                };

                console.log(recordsArr) // this logs out the records perfectly
                return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(recordsArr));
        });

    } catch (err) {

        return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({message: 'Error'}), { status: 500 })

    };

  return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(obj), { status: 200 });
}
```

As soon as I comment out the Airtable api call I stop getting the error.

If I move the entire Airtable API call to the client component it works flawlessly. So I think there is something about NextJS that I'm not comprehending.

Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I empathize with your situation as I faced the exact same issue a while ago. It took me a couple of hours to pinpoint the problem, but eventually I found the solution.

The issue with your code is the unnecessary use of the new keyword in your return statement. You're currently using this line:

```
return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(recordsArr));
```

So, what you should be doing instead is:

```
return NextResponse(JSON.stringify(recordsArr));
```

In my case, removing the **new** keyword was enough to resolve the issue.

If you're still having trouble, it could be beneficial to debug with a smaller piece of code or to isolate different parts of your code to pinpoint where the problem is originating from.

I hope this resolves your issue!

Comment: I really wish this was it. Unfortunately when I remove the new keyword I get `TypeError: Class constructor NextResponse cannot be invoked without 'new'`

Comment: I eventually was able to get removing the new keyword to work by moving my NextResponse outside of the jobs.select function. This worked and got rid of the error.

For anyone future coming across this. While this fixed the error, I was then having issues with the response finishing the airtable api call. To fix this I put the whole api call in a Promise. This resolved all issues.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you need to use a custom header for that Id?

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/headers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did try this. It doesn't seem to affect anything. Appreciate the idea.